# How can I build this layout with MaterialUI? React

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui

I'm using MaterialUI to build my UI with React.
I want to build a layout like this:
[image]

I'm handling with the Grid's components and playing around but need help to put that column :c any idea? Thanks.

Additional Details:
 * I've not thought in a responsive if you know a way to make it mobile it would be helpful

Thanks!

Comment: Please let me know what have you implemented and not working. Please share the relevant code so that we can help

Answer (score -1):

I'll grant that it's not the sexiest solution, but I believe the easiest route would be to use Material-UI's various Table components to create two columns and then nest your grid or a table in the first column.  If someone has a better alternative, please comment so I can learn, too!

In my example snippet, I reused the Table components to nest a table.  I didn't get the styling to match yours precisely but close enough for a workable starting point.

```js
const { Table, TableBody, TableRow, TableCell } = window["material-ui"];

const NestedTableExample = () => {
  const sharedColumnProps = { border: "none" };
  const sharedDivProps = {
    border: "solid 3px #000",
    height: "100%",
    padding: "10px",
    width: "100%"
  };
  const styles = {
    column1: { width: "150px", ...sharedColumnProps },
    column1Div: { background: "lightblue", ...sharedDivProps },
    column2: {
      width: "50px",
      ...sharedColumnProps
    },
    column2Div: {
      background: "orange",
      ...sharedDivProps
    }
  };
  return (
    <Table style={{ height: "100%" }}>
      <TableBody>
        <TableRow>
          <TableCell style={{ border: "none" }}>
            <Table>
              <TableBody>
                <TableRow>
                  <TableCell style={styles.column1}>
                    <div style={styles.column1Div}>Cell1</div>
                  </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow>
                  <TableCell style={styles.column1}>
                    <div style={styles.column1Div}>Cell2</div>
                  </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow>
                  <TableCell style={styles.column1}>
                    <div style={styles.column1Div}>Cell3</div>
                  </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              </TableBody>
            </Table>
          </TableCell>
          <TableCell style={styles.column2}>
            <div style={styles.column2Div}>Cell4</div>
          </TableCell>
        </TableRow>
      </TableBody>
    </Table>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<NestedTableExample />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@3.6.2/umd/material-ui.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```